# how to find an element in vector in the right way - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to remove an element from a vector. But I think, I have a specific problem:

**My data from file of reading:**

*move ctrl+a,F3*

*copy ctrl+v,shift+v*

*search F3,F4*

1. trying to read from a file
2. input a word ,which I want to earse(e.x.: move)
3. And the problem is that, I need to input ONLY ONE (like in an example) word, and earse the whole string of commands(*move ctrl+a,F3*).

   What I need is just to find a string by one word. But in code below I can't do this,help,please solving a problem. In a code below, all I can is find only one word, if in a file there is only one word, not like (*move ctrl+a,F3*), but if a string consists of several words.. It can't find.

   ```
    std::vector<std::string> HotMap::remove_element(std::vector<std::string> MyVector){
   //remove a element ,reading a vector of cmds, then deletting one chosen of them
   std::string delete_str;
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter_vec;

   std::cout << "Enter an element,which you want to delete: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> delete_str;
   for (auto & c : delete_str) c = tolower(c);                                         //For the standard for the right searching,all letters are in lower registr


   //Here, iter_ve is my vector(vec_get_smd) it swiches to algorithm 
   //std::ind that look for a cmd command ,which user is trying to input
   iter_vec = std::find(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), delete_str);

   if(iter_vec!= MyVector.end())                                                       //Check if is there an element that yoy want earse 
   {
       std::cout << "Found a element and earsed it!" << std::endl;
       MyVector.erase(iter_vec);
   }
   else
   {
       std::cout << "The element wasn't found!" << std::endl;
   }

   for (iter_vec = MyVector.begin(); iter_vec != MyVector.end(); ++iter_vec)           //Just for myself, showing results
   {
       std::cout << *iter_vec << std::endl;
   }

   return std::vector<std::string>(MyVector); }
   ```

   My results:

`read KEYS from a file TWO,below`

`move,fsf,fsdf,aaa`

`copy`

`search`

`Enter an element,which you want to delete:`
`move`

`The element wasn't found!`

Comment: "have an error,that is just can't run my exe file." - post the error

Comment: @Fureeish      " Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'B:\hot key\HotKeyMap\Debug\HotKeyMap.exe'" Just only this.

Comment: @x24 make sure no instance of your program is running. Windows has trouble writing to already open files.

Comment: You need to stop your program before you can rebuild it. This has nothing to do with your source code or algorithm or anything at all really. Just exit the program before rebuilding it.

Comment: @n.m.          please, look at the picture, I was trying to show my results.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post a [mcve] instead.

Comment: You will find that practically no one here will click a link without good reason. It is almost always better to reproduce text.

Comment: @n.m           it's my results of program. I was trying to follow your steps. Then I got this, how should I show my results? I can write it. I think, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Cut and paste it from the console to the question.. Also save yourself a bit of code and swap `for (iter_vec = MyVector.begin(); iter_vec != MyVector.end(); ++iter_vec)` for a range-based for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , you need to try to use `std::search()`:

`std::vector<std::string>` delete_word(“move”);

```
auto iterator=std::search (MyVector.begin(),MyVector.end(),delete_word.begin(), delete_word.end());
```

It tries to find your  **delete_word** in `MyVector`.